# React mouse events: onClick doesn't fire after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react application for drag and drop feature. Before dragging when I click the `<img>` the `onClick` fires and the `onClick` function definition works. After that I dragged the image and dropped inside a `div` then, the `onClick` event doesn't fire when I click the element.

What might be the reason? Can anyone help?

```
<img 
    id="drag1" 
    draggable="true" 
    onDragStart={this.drag.bind(this)} 
    onClick={this.click.bind(this)}
    alt="sample" src="designs.png">
</img>
```

Comment: Turns out I don't understand how onClick is supposed to work :s I dunno why it would behave like that but if you need something to happen after the drag finishes, you can use `onDragEnd` ?

Comment: I dont want anything to happens sudden after the drag ends. It should fire onClick only when the element is clicked again after it gets dropped.

Comment: I have been playing around a bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/l6681q3j9?fontsize=14 It would appear the `onClick` handler doesn't get called if you move the pointer away from the source of `mousedown`

Comment: So when you start dragging you click and hold the mouse button. When you stop dragging you release the held button. The `click` event is triggered after you press AND release but _on the same element_. After the "drag and drop" you probably release the mouse on top of a different element, so `click` is not triggered. More info here: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html